# Why is my C++ code still running? I see no reason

Tags: c++

It may be a quite simple issue but I can't figure it out. I have this code, really really basic code without even a conditional structure.
But even after the input, it won't stop running.  I must have done something wrong while cleaning the buffer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>



int main()
{
    std::string sentence{};

    std::cout << "Enter a sentence\n";

    std::cin >> sentence;

    std::cout << "Input sentence : " << sentence << std::endl;

    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
    
    return 0;
}
```

Btw I'm compiling with the following command:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++14 -o program
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you calling `std::cin.ignore` there?  Just don't call it.  [See the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: You could try with `if (std::streamsize n = std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()) { std::cin.ignore(n); }`

Comment: I don't see why you call `ignore`, but if you do, make it stop at a newline: `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` and then it should work.

Comment: `std::cin >> sentence;` will input a word, so if it is a one-word sentence, then it will input the entire sentence.  Otherwise, it will input just the first word of the sentence.  `getline(cin, setence);` will input the entire sentence (assuming there are no newline breaks mid-sentence, and the sentence is terminated with a newline).

Answer (score 6):

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
```

means to read and discard input until end-of-file is reached. That means that after you've given the first line of input, which the program receives and prints back to you, this function will just keep consuming input and doing nothing with it, because that's exactly what you told it to do. If you're running the program through a terminal, you should be able to signal the end of file with some key combination, which is usually Ctrl-D on Mac and Linux and Ctrl-Z on Windows. Then the call to `ignore` will return to `main`, which will then `return 0` and end the program.

Of course, there's no reason for the program to have this behavior. Just read the first line, print it, and then exit.

```
int main() {
    std::string sentence;
    std::cout << "Enter a sentence\n";
    std::cin >> sentence;
    std::cout << "Input sentence: " << sentence << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You don't *need* to call `clear` or `ignore`.

Comment: Thanks, way more understadable this way